# These PDF seems identical in VSCode but different in PDF viewver

Tags: api, pdf, postman, fpdf

I have two PDF generated by an api **using the same route**.

[The first one](http://www.elia-medical.com/docs/from-postman.pdf) is saved from Postman and its size is 1.7 Mo and is good in PDF viewver.

[The second one](http://www.elia-medical.com/docs/from-safari.pdf) is saved from chrome and its size is 3.1 Mo and is white in PDF viewer.

When i open these two files in Visual Studio Code and i compare them, **the only différence is the creation date** :

First file :  /CreationDate (D:20200120202232)
Second file : /CreationDate (D:20200120201345)

**So I can think that these two files are identical but not**

Finaly if i save the first file in VSCode the new file size is 3.1 Mo and the file is white in pdf viewer like the second.

I don't understand what's happend... Someone understands something about this issue ?

Comment: PDFs are not text. You cannot compare them with a text comparison tool like VS Code. Use a hex editor.

Comment: Your second file "from-safari.pdf" is damaged. That's not a good sign. The damage – conversion of high bytes to something like UTF-8 – added around 1436066 bytes to the file.

Comment: I see. Thank you for these comments  @usr2564301 , I trusted what I saw in VS Code but indeed with a hexadecimal editor I can see the difference. So I'm going to look for the API side. thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks too @ianKemp.